# How to add an AJAX request into Google Map JS code

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, google-maps

I'm trying to pass the Latitude and Longitude values obtained from the location searched by a user (refer to the screenshot for an example) and pass them to a controller class in my Spring MVC framework. (I intend to compare the latitude and longitude values to other latitude and longitude values in a MySQL database). It will return ratings into the textfield boxes below based on the location that is searched by the user. Being unfamiliar with this type of multi-language communication I did some research and it seems that AJAX can be used for what I'm trying to achieve. However, I'm running into trouble as to how I integrate that into the JS code below.

[image: Screenshot of index.html page]

Essentially what happens is the "Locate" button calls the JS function that will search the location and calculate the latitude and longitude. I'm a bit unclear about if an AJAX request can pass the same latitude and longitude values to the controller class when the same "Locate" button is pressed?

**index.html**

```
//I've omitted snippets of irrelevant code for conciseness


<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

/*
 * Google Map with marker
 */
function initialize() {
    var initialLat = $('.search_latitude').val();
    var initialLong = $('.search_longitude').val();
    initialLat = initialLat?initialLat:53.350140;
    initialLong = initialLong?initialLong:-6.266155;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(initialLat, initialLong);
    var options = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("geomap"), options);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: latlng
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        var point = marker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(point);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                $('.search_addr').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            }
        });
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //load google map
    initialize();

    /*
     * autocomplete location search
     */
    var PostCodeid = '#search_location';
    $(function () {
        $(PostCodeid).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': request.term
                }, function (results, status) {
                    response($.map(results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.formatted_address,
                            value: item.formatted_address,
                            lat: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                            lon: item.geometry.location.lng()
                        };
                    }));
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('.search_addr').val(ui.item.value);
                $('.search_latitude').val(ui.item.lat);
                $('.search_longitude').val(ui.item.lon);
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.lat, ui.item.lon);
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                initialize();
            }
        });
    });

    /*
     * Point location on google map
     */
    $('.get_map').click(function (e) {
        var address = $(PostCodeid).val();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                $('.search_addr').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //Add listener to marker for reverse geocoding
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('.search_addr').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

geocoder.geocode({
    'address': request.term,
    componentRestrictions: {country: "ie"}
})

function loginAlert(){
    alert("User must be logged in to view reports");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Area Rating System</h3>
    <h5>Please register with a valid Username and password below!</h5>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Username &nbsp;  </td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>

                <td>Password  &nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}" />&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>

                <td><button type="submit">Register</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href = "login.html">Already registered? Log in here</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br></br>


<form>
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="text" id="search_location" class="form-control" placeholder="Search location"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default get_map" type="submit">
            Locate
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- display google map -->
<div id="geomap"></div>

<div id="forminputs">
<table>
<tr>
<!-- display selected location information -->
<th>
<h4>Location Details</h4>
<p>Address: &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" class="search_addr" size="45"/></p>
<p>Latitude: &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" class="search_latitude" size="30"/></p>
<p>Longitude: <input type="text" class="search_longitude" size="30"/></p>
<p style = "height: 120px"></p>

</th>
<th style = "width: 100px">  </th>
<th>
<h4>Area Rating</h4>
<p>Average House Price: <input type="text"  size="10"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="loginAlert();">Full Report</a></p>
<p>Crime Rating: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text"  size="10"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="loginAlert();">Full Report</a></p>


</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do jQuery, but I can try to give you the method using JS. However, I have never used Spring MVC so I will give my answer in how I would use PHP to do the MySQL update. Hopefully this can give you some ideas so you can extrapolate what you need to your language of choice.

Now that you already have the values you need:

```
var Lat = $('.search_latitude').val();
var Long = $('.search_longitude').val();
```

You want to run an AJAX function when "Locate" button is pressed, so that you can send the latitude and longitude values to your MySQL  like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-default get_map" type="submit" onclick="sendLatLong();">
        Locate
    </button>

<script>
function sendLatLong() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create our XMLHttpRequest object

var url = "toMySQL.php"; // This PHP file will query the database (MySQL)
                         // and do the comparison you want.

var coor = "lat="+Lat+"&long="+Long;
xhr.open("POST", url, true);

// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = xhr.responseText;
        // For simplicty I just return whatever result into a <DIV id="status">
        // You may populate other input fields with your data 
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    xhr.send(coor);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

Now the PHP-file "toMySQL.php" queries the database table and based on the variables you just sent it will make the comparison and send back the result.

Let me know if you need any further clarifications.
Good luck to you!

Comment: I haven't used PHP before either but I think this will send me in the right direction. Thanks!